# Escape sequence for python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write below code to a file using python's open. However, I'm unable to place the escape sequence "\" in proper place which in turn throws error.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open("hello.service", "w")
f.write("[Unit]")
f.write("Description=Hello World")
f.write("[Service]")
f.write("ExecStart=/bin/bash -c \"while true; do echo \"Hello, world"\; sleep 1; done""\)

f.close()
```

**Error:**

```
$ python hello.py
  File "hello.py", line 7
    f.write("ExecStart=/bin/bash -c \"while true; do echo \"Hello, world"\; sleep 1; done""\)
                                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: I think it should be `world\"` for escaping `"` and after `done\""`

Comment: check the colors in your question: they help :)

Comment: pro-tip: use triple-quotes so you don't have to escape anything: `"""A string "with some double quotes" and 'some single quotes'"""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

f = open("hello.service", "w")
f.write("[Unit]")
f.write("Description=Hello World")
f.write("[Service]")
f.write("ExecStart=/bin/bash -c \"while true; do echo \"Hello, world\"; sleep 1; done\"")

f.close()
```

The `\` always needs to precede the `"`, even if it's a closing `"`.

Answer (score 1):

... when i mess with .shp files i have to use a ; after every ""\

```
f.write("ExecStart=/bin/bash -c \"while true; do echo \"Hello, world"\; sleep 1; done""\>>>>>>>>>>>>>;<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<)
```

minus the arrows....

I hope that this helps...

-Cheers